# ZF 1.12 : How to render form element error message separately?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I am using **zf 1.12**, I am rendering label and element separately for `dob`. How can I get the error message of this element separately ? Below is my view code for the element `dob`.

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <?php echo $this->form->getElement('dob')->renderLabel(); ?>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->form->getElement('dob')->renderViewHelper(); ?>
        <ul class="errors"><li><?php echo $this->form->getMessages('dob'); ?></li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to get the error message using below code.

```
<?php echo $this->form->getMessages('dob'); ?>
```

But it gives me an array with a key of validation as follows.

```
Array
(
    [isEmpty] => Value is required and can't be empty
)
```

I want to get the error message directly ? is there any way to get it directly ? Please help for this.